# Laravel 8 blade File not rendering but shows when I view page source

Tags: php, laravel, rendering, laravel-blade

This is my show method

public function show($id){
$student = Student::find($id);

```
    return view('students.student-detail', ['student' => $student]);
    
}
```

Routes

```
Route::get('/', [LoginController::class, 'index']);


/* Dashboard routes */
Route::get('/dashboard',    [DashboardController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/student-info', [StudentController::class,   'dashboard']);
Route::get('/parent-info',  [ParentController::class,    'dashboard']);
Route::get('/teacher-info', [TeacherController::class,   'dashboard']);


/* Student routes */
Route::get( '/students', [StudentController::class, 'index']);
//Route::get( '/student-detail/{id}', [StudentController::class, 'studentDetail']);
Route::get( '/student-detail/{id}', [StudentController::class, 'show']);
Route::get( '/admit',  [StudentController::class, 'create']);
Route::post('/admit', [StudentController::class, 'store']);
Route::get('/admit/edit/{id}', [StudentController::class, 'edit']);


Blade View
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
        <div class="dashboard-content-one">
            <!-- Breadcubs Area Start Here -->
            <div class="breadcrumbs-area">
                <h3>Students</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>Student Details</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- Breadcubs Area End Here -->
            <!-- Student Details Area Start Here -->
            <div class="card height-auto">
                <div class="card-body" style="margin-top: -1.5rem;">
                    <div class="heading-layout1">
                        <div class="item-title">
                            <h3>About Me</h3>
                        </div>
                       <div class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button"
                            data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">...</a>

                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-eye text-orange-red"></i> View</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="admit/edit/"><i class="fas fa-cogs text-dark-pastel-green"></i> Update</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-times text-orange-peel"></i> Suspend</a> </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="single-info-details">
                        <div class="item-img">
                            <img src="img/figure/student1.jpg" alt="student">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item-content">
                            <div class="header-inline item-header">
                                <h3 class="text-dark-medium font-medium">{{$student->first_name . " " . $student->last_name}}</h3>
                                <div class="header-elements">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-print"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-download"></i></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <p>{{ $student->bio }}</p>
                            <div class="info-table table-responsive">
                                <table class="table text-nowrap">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Name:</td>
                                            <td class="font-medium text-dark-medium">{{$student->first_name . " " . $student->last_name}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Gender:</td>
                                            <td class="font-medium text-dark-medium">{{$student->gender->name}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Father Name:</td>
                                            <td class="font-medium text-dark-medium">{{ $student->parents->first_name . " " . $student->parents->last_name }}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Mother Name:</td>
                                            <td class="font-medium text-dark-medium">{{ $student->parents->spouse_first_name . " " . $student->parents->spouse_last_name }}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Date Of Birth:</td>
                                            <td class="font-medium text-dark-medium">{{$student->dob}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Religion:</td>
                                            <td class="font-medium text-dark-medium">{{$student->religion->name}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Father Occupation:</td>
                                            <td class="font-medium text-dark-medium">{{$student->parents->occupation}}</td>}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>E-mail:</td>
                                            <td class="font-medium text-dark-medium">{{$student->email}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Admission Date:</td>
                                            <td class="font-medium text-dark-medium">{{$student->created_at}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Class:</td>
                                            <td class="font-medium text-dark-medium">{{$student->classes->name}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Section:</td>
                                            <td class="font-medium text-dark-medium">{{$student->section->name}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Roll:</td>
                                            <td class="font-medium text-dark-medium">{{$student->admission_id}}</td></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Address:</td>
                                            <td class="font-medium text-dark-medium">{{ $student->home_address }},{{$student->lga->name}},{{$student->state->name}} State</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Phone:</td>
                                            <td class="font-medium text-dark-medium">{{$student->phone}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Student Details Area End Here -->
@endsection
```

I am passing the data from the student to the show method. when I dd($students) it returns data for students/student-detail/1 e.t.c

but when I take out the dump and reload, it comes up blank.

so I decided to check if the data is coming to the view at all by viewing page source. When I do this, I see the results in the respective html elements as desired but it just wouldn't render.

Please can anyone help?

Comment: Sounds weird.. If you can see the html content in the page inspector, it should also be rendered on the screen unless you got some sort of container covering it all up with a white background :) Try another web-browser or open the page in inkognito mode to verify that it is not some cache that is causing this problem.

Comment: Have opened it in in-cognito mode. still, no response

Comment: Sounds like there is something weird going on. If you can see it when you inspect the page, it should be visible. Are you sure that you do not have a display: none; on the container or something? :S Something with your styling must be wrong

Comment: @EricQvarnström, I will wait for you on this zoom link. Let's look at it together.

Comment: Join Zoom Meeting
https://us04web.zoom.us/j/79457337152?pwd=eW1OSitkZGRYYzNNdVJyZmRVMzdKUT09

Meeting ID: 794 5733 7152
Passcode: sZ4Ch7

Comment: https://us04web.zoom.us/j/79457337152?pwd=eW1OSitkZGRYYzNNdVJyZmRVMzdKUT09

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What caused the blank screen was a plain declaration of javascript files in the footer. I was meant to use laravel assets to include project dependencies. like;
scr = "{{assets('/js/another_directory/file.js')}}".

Once I did that, the page rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function show($id){ 
    $student = Student::find($id)->first();
    return view('students.student-detail', ['student' => $student]);
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function show($id){ 
    $student = Student::find($id)->first();
    return view('students.student-detail',compact('student')); 
}
```

for reference visit this url:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-for-passing-data-to-view-in-laravel/

Comment: I have tried that too. still, it's not rendering.